# Looping the WHERE section of mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm trying to determine whether a combination of topics related to a category is unique. This is done while adding topics to a category. The uniqueness is checked with this query:

```
$sql_unique = "SELECT Categories_CategoryID, list
FROM (

SELECT Categories_CategoryID, GROUP_CONCAT( Topics_TopicID ) AS list
FROM (

SELECT *
FROM Topics_crosstable
ORDER BY Topics_TopicID
)H
GROUP BY Categories_CategoryID
)A
WHERE list = (
SELECT GROUP_concat( TopicID )
FROM Topics
WHERE Name = 'nr1'
OR Name = 'nr2'
ORDER BY Categories_CategoryID ASC )";


$result = mysql_query($sql_unique);
echo mysql_num_rows($result);

 if($result > 1)
 {
    echo' HELP! It is not unique';
 }
 else
 {
 echo ' getshere';
 }
```

This works fine. The problem is however, the number of topics that are added is variant. So is there some way to include a for loop in the where section of the query?

Something like for(number of topics added; nr++) {OR Name =', $inserted_topicName '}

Comment: Hi, it would be nice if you included some example of valid data in your question. do i understand it right, that this is right: **topic:cars, categories:volvo, bmw, skoda, opel; topic: bikes, categories: yamaha, suzuki** while this is wrong: **topic:cars, categories:volvo, bmw, skoda, opel; topic: bikes, categories: yamaha, suzuki, bmw** because bmw is already in cars?

Comment: No, actually it's the other way around.
So: Category: Cars; has topics: BMW, Suzuki

There may not be another category like: Category: Bikes; has topics: BMW, Suzuki

While Category: Bikes; Topics: BMW, Suzuki, Yamaha.
would be ok because the combination is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of 'WHERE ... IN':

```
WHERE Name IN ('nr1','nr2',...)
```

And

```
string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces );
```

Use as follows:

```
$options = array(); //here's your choices

$sql_unique = "SELECT Categories_CategoryID, list
               FROM (
             SELECT Categories_CategoryID, GROUP_CONCAT( Topics_TopicID ) AS list
             FROM (
                SELECT *
                FROM Topics_crosstable
                ORDER BY Topics_TopicID
             )H
             GROUP BY Categories_CategoryID
                )A
                WHERE list = (
             SELECT GROUP_concat( TopicID )
             FROM Topics
             WHERE Name IN (";
$sql_unique .= implode(",",$options);
$sql_unique .= ") ORDER BY Categories_CategoryID ASC )";
```

Answer (score 0):

table **Categories**

- catID

table **Topics**

- topID
- category

Categories : Topics ( 1 : n )

**Question: does category `$x` have unique set of topics?**

first get sum of all topics of category `$x`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(topID ORDER BY topID) topiclist
FROM Topics
WHERE category='$x'
```

you may need to explode the `topiclist` and add some new values to that array, I am assuming that the result of the above query was fetched into an associative array `$r`

```
$list=explode(',',$r['topiclist']);
$list[]=$newtopicID1;
$list[]=$newtopicID2;
// etc ... or use $list += $newTopicsArray; which will ADD those two arrays
sort($list); //make it sorted again
$list=implode(',',$list);
```

and then query the database again, trying to find such a combination excluding the category i am querying:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(topID ORDER BY topID) topiclist
FROM Topics
WHERE category!='$x'
GROUP BY category
HAVING topiclist='$list'
```

then check whether there is some record returned. If so, then you found another category with the same topics, if not, then the combination of topics is unique